# How to fix "TypeError: Cannot call method "trim" of undefined"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror

I'm using an app script in Google Sheets to provide a Status Code in column B for a list of URLs in column A (i.e. www.test.com >>> returns 404, 300, 200, etc.) The code was working properly until today, but is now throwing an error:

```
function getStatusCode(url){
var options = {
 'muteHttpExceptions': true,
 'followRedirects': false
};
var url_trimmed = url.trim();
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_trimmed, options);
return response.getResponseCode();
}
```

Here is the error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "trim" of undefined. (line 6, file "Code")

Nothing has changed since yesterday so I am unsure if this is a Google issue, or something else. My appscript knowledge is very limited so please be kind :D

Comment: Is it a custom function? If so, you can't call it from the editor. `=getStatusCode("www.test.com")` should work.

Comment: Bri, what makes you think that the code isn't working except for this error? If it ever worked before, then it should be run as a custom function in a way mentioned by TheMaster above. Is there a problem *when you call it as a custom function*?

Answer (score 0):

`trim()` is a method of [String.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/prototype), that means that, in this case, the value of `url` should be an string literal, a String type object or an object that has the `toString()` so it's able to return a String value when it's required.

Considering the above, the error occurs becasue `url` doesn't meet the conditions mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that everything else works then try this:

```
function getStatusCode(url){
  var url=url||'default url...you fill this in with your url and run it from script editor'
  var options = {
   'muteHttpExceptions': true,
   'followRedirects': false
};
  if(url) {
    var url_trimmed = url.trim();
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_trimmed, options);
    Logger.log(response.getReponseCode());
    return response.getResponseCode();
   }else{
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Invalid or Missing Url');
   }
}
```